# Set a Macro before sending log over network with syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng

I have created a syslog server and client. I want to set client serial number in SOURCE macro in all logs being sent to server so that on server side I can retrieve the macro and can create the log file based on client serial number. Following is my rewrite rule:

```
rewrite set_host{
    set("DEVICE_SERIAL_NO", value("SOURCE"));
```

};

log { source(s_src); rewrite(set_host); destination(d_net); };

On server side I have written following configuration for log file:

```
destination d_host-specific {
    file("/var/log/testlogs/$SOURCE/$YEAR/$MONTH/$HOST-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.log");
```

};

But on server side I get value of $SOURCE as s_net. Seems like SOURCE macro is over-written on server side. How to sustain a macro from client to server and use it on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$SOURCE` is a local value, it is not forwarded to the server by default. Every destination has an on-wire format, for example, the `network()` source/destination uses the BSD (RFC 3164) or IETF (RFC 5424) syslog protocol. The default template of these protocols contains `$PROGRAM`, `$MSG`, `$HOST`, `$ISODATE`, etc., but `$SOURCE` is not a standard field.

You have multiple options:

1. You can specify a destination `template()` manually and then parse the message on the server side. This can be done, for example, in JSON format (`$(format-json)` and `json-parser()`).
2. You can use the structured-data section of a RFC 5424 syslog message:

```
# client

rewrite set_host {
  set("DEVICE_SERIAL_NO", value(".SDATA.example@32473.SOURCE"));
};

destination d_net {
  syslog("server.address");
};
```

```
# server

source s_net {
  syslog();
};

destination d_host_specific {
  file("/var/log/testlogs/${.SDATA.example@32473.SOURCE}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$HOST-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.log");
};
```

The `syslog()` and the `network(flags(syslog-protocol))` destinations forward messages using the IETF syslog protocol. All subkeys under `.SDATA` will be serialized automatically into the forwarded message.

3. syslog-ng >= v3.17 has a dedicated source/destination plugin that transfers messages "in whole" between syslog-ng instances (containing all name-value pairs) in a special format. Both the source and destination objects are called `ewmm()` ([enterprise wide message model](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/blob/master/scl/ewmm/ewmm.conf)).
4. As an alternative, you can use `$HOST` with (`keep-hostname(yes)` on the server side), which is part of the message header.

Comment: I tried setting HOST parameter too. It gets changed when I receive the message on server.

Comment: Also, the solution provided above didn't work. I am using syslog-ng 3.13.

Comment: If you want to keep the original hostname, set `keep-hostname(yes)` in the server config.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: By "didn't work" I mean that on server side I get .SDATA.example@32473.SOURCE as empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101206/discussion-between-mranno-and-darshan-prajapati).

Comment: Having keep-hostname(yes) on server side and setting HOST on client side it worked. @MrAnno just change the answer with this and I will mark it as accepted answer.